# How to move up all component on screen when open keyboard in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two components: black and red.

After opening the keyboard only the red component moves up. The black component is not moving. That means the red component stacks on the black component. How can I make both move up the same height?

[image: Without keyboard]
[image: With keyboard]

I created a snack on expo.
Link: https://snack.expo.io/@qngnud/fcda3e

Comment: Can you share styles from `Black` and `Red` components?

Comment: I added the style

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour with the code you shared. Look out for some fixed heights. If you still need help, please share Expo Snack or similar.

Comment: Hi @Darko, I made a reproduce, can you check it, link above question :D thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with setting `minHeight` for the bottom component (`Red`).
When the Keyboard is opened the screen height becomes smaller and with your styles `flex: 3` and `flex: 2` for `Black` and `Red` components, the bottom component becomes smaller too and there is no room for the form elements.

Depending on your use case and what you need to display in the `Black` component choose appropriate `minHeight` values.

Check https://snack.expo.io/zxZxvX0Ol